# Bash check if grep matches string

Tags: bash, grep

I am writing a bash script that checks every 5 minutes if there is from an IP address 100 or more invalid passwords (brute force attack) attempts.

The following script works:

```
blockIPs="$(cat /var/log/secure | grep "Failed password for" | grep -v "invalid" | awk {'print $11'} | sort | uniq -c | awk -v limit=100 '$1 > limit{print $2}')"

while read -r line; do
 iptables -A INPUT -s $line -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
 echo "Blocking IP address: $line"
done <<< "$blockIPs"
```

The problem with the script above is that after an hour I have duplicate entries in `iptables`. So I tried to extend my script with a check if the IP address is already blocked, if so, it should skip it.

This is the script:

```
blockIPs="$(cat /var/log/secure | grep "Failed password for" | grep -v "invalid" | awk {'print $11'} | sort | uniq -c | awk -v limit=100 '$1 > limit{print $2}')"
currentIPs="$(iptables-save)"

while read -r line; do
 if grep -q $line $currentIPs
 then
 echo "IP address already blocked, skipping"
 else
 iptables -A INPUT -s $line -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
 echo "Blocking IP address: $line"
 fi
done <<< "$blockIPs"
```

But for some reasons it is not working and I am getting weird output:

```
grep: 2: No such file or directory
grep: 18:19:53: No such file or directory
grep: 2015: No such file or directory
Blocking IP address: 59.47.0.152
grep: #: No such file or directory
grep: Generated: No such file or directory
grep: by: No such file or directory
grep: iptables-save: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong with my script?

Comment: `grep -q $line $currentIPs` try quoting your variables.

Comment: The lack of quotes around variables is indeed what's causing confusion. Also necessary reading would be most of the Bash FAQ, starting with http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're basically doing is:

```
grep -q test  this is a string that contains the word test
```

hoping to match a word in a string. Grep thinks each of the words is a file, and gives output like you're seeing:

```
grep: this: No such file or directory
grep: is: No such file or directory
grep: a: No such file or directory
grep: string: No such file or directory
```

To match in a literal string instead of files, send the string on stdin:

```
if grep -q "$line" <<< "$currentIPs"
```

Though you would be better off using glob matching:

```
if [[ "$currentIPs" = *"$line"* ]]
```

Note that if you've banned `1.2.3.45`, `1.2.3.4` will match and therefore not get banned. You can use the above approach with `*" $line "*` to ensure there are spaces around it, if your input has that.

Also consider just installing fail2ban which does this automatically in a robust way.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `if grep -q $line $currentIPs` to:

```
if echo "$currentIPs" |grep -q "$line"
```